# Multiple owners of a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet and I am the owner of it. My colleague often wants ownership access of it, so we have to toggle the ownership between us by changing the Status every time. Is there a way I can have multiple owners for a Google Sheet? If it means using the App Script code, I am open to it too (I tried to find a code but haven't seen it yet).

Hoping to get help from folks here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the current stage, it seems that the Spreadsheet has one owner. So, in your case, how about adding the users to the Spreadsheet as the editor?

Comment: Put the Spreadsheet in a Shared Drive and give everyone full access

Comment: Another way is top use service accounts and let the code runn as the "service account"

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. A google spreadsheet can have **only one** owner.

There are 4 different levels of permissions to allow for flexibility and control over security and access around users:

1. Ownership
2. Edit
3. Comment
4. View

If we assume that the **owner** does not have special protected ranges or sheets, which can only be edited by him/her, an **editor** can have the same privileges when it comes to editing/modifying the content as well as being able to share the file with other users. A spreadsheet file can have **multiple users** that belong to categories 2,3 and 4, but only owner (category 1).

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be more than one Owner at a time. Transferring ownership in Google drive will lead the documents to be organized in a single folder, titled with the previous Owner’s email address. The original Owner will still have only the editing privileges.